# Can you only install and not try ubuntu from a live usb in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: live-usb, live-environment

Yesterday I made a clone of an older hard drive (Ubuntu Server 16.04) which I fear will die pretty soon. Switched the drives and wanted to boot with a live USB drive to change the uuid from the boot drive and fix the grub.

The only problem is I don't get the choice to between "Trying" and "Installing" Ubuntu. I am directly in the installation process and don't have the live environment from "Trying Ubuntu".

About the live USB drive :

- 16 Gb USB2
- Used the documentation from the ubuntu.com page : https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview
- Used the latest ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso from the official website
- No problems booting from it since I can install from it

About the system :

- Both the system and used ISO are 64bit (the actually running 16.04)
- I plug in the USB drive, power on the system, go into the BIOS to root from USB
- I tried the installation process and the installation works like it should, too bad I don't need it...

To be honest I haven't used a live USB drive/CD for something other than installing Ubuntu in probably the last 5 or 6 years. I searched a bit on the internet and find screen captures where you have the choice between "Trying" and "Installing" like I remember.

Do I miss something extremely obvious how to get to the "Try Ubuntu" part of the live USB drive or did they cut it from the 20.04 releases?

Comment: Wlcome to Ask Ubuntu. I don't think server has ever had a try option. Ubuntu Desktop should have everything you need, to do what you want to do. https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment of @https://askubuntu.com/users/43926/c-s-cameron is right. In fact you can't "try Ubuntu" with a server version. I downloaded the desktop version of the ISO and achieved what I wanted to do.